custom domain mapping and authentication issues
I’m currently working on an application where I’m using Django, GCP MySQL (database). I deployed the application using Google cloud run and I can access the website through its url. Where I’m an facing issue is when linking my registered custom domain with Django, I’m able to access the website when I go to my custom domain url but I’m not able to login through the same url. It gets me redirected again to the login page, instead of going to the homepage, and it also doesn’t give me credentials error when I enter incorrect password/email. Note it works properly when I access it through cloud run service url/ localhost.
I really wish I could post some error logs here, but there’s none. I checked the GCP logging service but there’s no error regarding this. I can explain a bit though. After I enter my credentials (url - https://custom-domain.org/login), it shows the login page which is the same url. When I check the logs there’s a successful 302 get request for the home page i.e. https://custom-domain.org, but then there another log having the login request url - https://custom-domain.org/login.
I have mapped the cloud run domain url https://iconnect-webapp-dxxqb7rbaa-uk.a.run.app/ to mu custom domain url. when I try to access the website with custom domain, then the logs record the domain as cloud run domain instead of custom domain in the logging dashboard.
enter image description here
If anyone have any idea or suggestions regarding this issue, kindly help me out here.
This is my first time posting in an online community. I’m sorry if it is hard to understand, I really tried my best to explain. Feel free to comment any questions or clarifying doubts, I will try to answer.
